# Hay alguna forma de ejecutar una app en iOS sin cable?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilar, macos

Me surge esta duda, ya que el teclado y el raton del mac se conectan por bluetooth y apple tiene otras tecnologías de conexión inalámbrica entre dispositivos como el airdrop, se puede de alguna manera compilar una aplicación por bluetooth o wifi? he buscado al respecto y no hay gran cosa.

La idea sería algo como el testflight pero para compilar en local sin generar una versión

Comment: La compilación no tiene nada que ver con cables... o me estoy perdiendo de algo?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "compilar en local sin generar una versión"?

Comment: Es justo lo que han respondido, compilar y ejecutar en un dispositivo sin tener que tenerlo conectado por cable al mac, lo siento si me expresé un poco mal. @fredyfx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es ejecutar una aplicación en un dispositivo físico de forma inalámbrica en lugar de tenerlo conectado al equipo con el cable. Para ello tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Conecta el dispositivo al equipo por cable.
2. Abre Xcode, ve a **Window -> Devices and Simulators**.

Se te abrirá una ventana parecida a esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es activar la casilla que dice "**Connect vía network**", y esperar a que aparezca la bolita a la derecha del nombre del dispositivo.

Ahora cierras esa ventana, desconectas el dispositivo por cable y ejecutas. Si todo fue bien, se cargará la app en el dispositivo y podrás funcionar con ella.

Comment: Para que me funcionara tuve que hacer click derecho en el nombre del dispositivo y seleccionar la opción de conectar por IP e introducir la IP del dispositivo, pero ahora ya me funciona la ejecución de manera inalámbrica. Gracias!